# How to extract array column by selecting one field of struct-array column in PySpark

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, struct

I have a dataframe `df` containing a struct-array column `properties` (array column whose elements are struct fields having keys `x` and `y`) and I want to create a new array column by extracting the `x` values from column `properties`.

A sample input dataframe would be something like this

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

data = [
  (1, [{'x':11, 'y':'str1a'}, ]), 
  (2, [{'x':21, 'y':'str2a'}, {'x':22, 'y':0.22, 'z':'str2b'}, ]), 
    ]
my_schema = StructType([
    StructField('id', LongType()),
    StructField('properties', ArrayType(
      StructType([
        StructField('x', LongType()),
        StructField('y', StringType()),
                  ])
    )           
               ),
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=my_schema)
df.show()
# +---+--------------------+
# | id|          properties|
# +---+--------------------+
# |  1|       [[11, str1a]]|
# |  2|[[21, str2a], [22...|
# +---+--------------------+

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- id: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- properties: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- x: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- y: string (nullable = true)
```

On the other hand, the desired output `df_new` should look like

```py
df_new.show()
# +---+--------------------+--------+
# | id|          properties|x_values|
# +---+--------------------+--------+
# |  1|       [[11, str1a]]|    [11]|
# |  2|[[21, str2a], [22...|[21, 22]|
# +---+--------------------+--------+

df_new.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- id: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- properties: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- x: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- y: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- x_values: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

**Does anybody know a solution for such task?**

Ideally, *I am looking for a solution which operates row-by-row without relying on `F.explode`*.
In fact in my actual database I have not identified an equivalent to `id` column yet, and after calling `F.explode` I would not be sure of how to coalesce back together the exploded values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `properties.x` then all values are extracted from the properties array.

**Example:**

```
df.withColumn("x_values",col("properties.x")).show(10,False)

#or by using higher order functions
df.withColumn("x_values",expr("transform(properties,p -> p.x)")).show(10,False)

#+---+-------------------------+--------+
#|id |properties               |x_values|
#+---+-------------------------+--------+
#|1  |[[11, str1a]]            |[11]    |
#|2  |[[21, str2a], [22, 0.22]]|[21, 22]|
#+---+-------------------------+--------+
```